# How to take the actionscript from an as3 package and use it in .fla

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air, package

This morning i stumbled upon this source code for a miner game : http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2010/10/22/create-a-flash-game-like-gold-miner-as3-version/

The problem is that I never used packages and classes before ( I only worked with as2 ) .

I need the code from the AS files to be in the timeline AS but cant figure out a way to have it there and working .

If anybody knows how please tell me .

I tried copy/pasting the code , removing the package,class and private text and it still doesn't work .

Any help is apreciated.

Chris

Comment: It's not that simple, you're trying to move to a **function oriented** paradigm from an **object-oriented** paradigm.

Comment: Why do you need the code in the timeline? You can use document classes in the Flash IDE property window.

Comment: @ Mattias I need the code in the timeline because I want to use this for a Adobe AIR app for Android phones . And cant have the AS somewhere else because it doesn't recognize it ...

Comment: @chris - while I am yet to develop on the Android, it is extremely unlikely that the only way to develop for it is on the timeline. I will eat my hat if it is :). Sounds like you have not set up the packages and classes correctly (regardless of what device you are publishing for).

Comment: Argh you are right . I didn`t declare the Class in the flash :| . I feel dumb now :D

Comment: Thanks to everyone who contributed . Managed to get it to work fine now .

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to put all this packages in their own file and name the file after the class name, for instance the Main class should be saved as Main.as.

After you've saved each class in its own .as file , take all these files and copy them in the same folder as your fla. The reason for this is that the packages don't specify a path ( something like com.example for instance ) , so they need to be at the same directory level as your fla.

Finally , just use the Main class as your Document Class, here's a tutorial , 
there are plenty of examples on the web anyway...
http://www.heaveninteractive.com/2008/03/04/introduction-to-the-document-class-in-actionscript-30-tutorial/

Test your swf...

Answer (score 0):

I assume that AS3 package lookups work pretty much like AS2 classes in that they're relative to root directories pointed to by your Flash movie.

For example, the package i.am.a.test{}, would exist at:

i/am/a/test

(Of course, the path above would be relative either to the .fla using it, or to another directory specified in your movie settings.)

...And with a class definition would be something like:

```
package i.am.a.test
{
    class ReallyATest
    {
    }
}
```

So, what you need to do is ensure all classes used in the .fla exist in the path relative to the .fla you're working on. Here's a little more info you can use to read up on working with packages: [creating a package](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/creating_class_as3.html)